# Adding alert to existing indicator

Tags: pine-script

I have been trying to add an alert to an existing indicator but without success so far...

The indicator is called **Premarket High/Low**

This is how i tried to do it :-

```
Cross1 = cross(close, day_low)
Cross2 = cross(close, day_high)

alertcondition(condition=(Cross1 or Cross2), message='Price Crossed Pre Market Level')
```

Thanks!

Edit: tried it like this but unfortunately with no alert being triggered either:

```
alertcondition(cross(close,day_low), message = 'Price crossed Pre Market level')
```